# Rails vanity gem custom metric error: private method `to_time' called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, rubygems, private, vanity

Hi I am trying to setup Vanity gem into a rail 3 application.
I am creating a custom metric to experiment a bit.

So I created it following the suggestions on [their website](https://github.com/assaf/vanity):

```
metric "Signups" do
  description "Signups completed"
  def values(from, to)
    (from..to).map { |i| 24 }
  end
end
```

- The file is located at the right place and is loaded, vanity picks it up but somehow it looks like there is an internal error in the way vanity works.
- Of course: those values are only there for a testing purpose, they will be replaced by real ones later.

I get the following error when running this experiment

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an error in the gem:

in this file
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/vanity-1.7.1/lib/vanity/templates/_metric.erb

where we can read the following line

```
js = data.map { |date,value| "['#{**date.to_time.httpdate**}',#{value}]" }.join(",")
  vanity_html_safe(%{<div class="chart"></div>
```

if we change **date.to_time.httpdate** to **date.to_s.to_time.httpdate** it works.